# USA fingerprint on arrival

Tags: usa, uk, biometric-passports

In 2001 I claimed asylum in the UK using a different name and date of birth and I was also fingerprinted. The application was refused and I was later granted indefinite leave to remain in that fake name.
I now have a British passport in my real name and date of birth after being granted indefinite leave following 10 years student visa.
I now want to travel to USA.
Will the US border control find my fingerprints in a different name from UK?

Comment: Do you already have an ESTA? Did you hold a travel document in your previous name? AFAIK, applying for an ESTA requires you to disclose whether you’ve ever held a passport or identity card issued by a country other than the one that issued your current passport.

Comment: Where did you claim asylum in 2001?

Comment: Has the US ever had reason to query your fingerprints before?

Comment: If you don't mind saying, what was your citizenship before you went to the UK?

Comment: Have you come clean with British authorities about your alias (fake name)? Were you fingerprinted when you obtained the British identity documents under your real name?

Comment: The edit says the asylum was claimed in the UK. However, is that really true?

Comment: To be honest, I am surprised you would even be granted infinite leave to remain, and a passport after being untruthful. But I wouldn't rely that nobody notices there exist two people with identical fingerprints in the database (which is _of course_ shared). If FVEY aren't totally incompetent idiots (and you had better assume they're not) then the computer system detects this automatically, and your fingerprint has a red flag already anyway, so it is detected the instant you put your finger on a sensor.

Comment: @Damon I'm sure that quite a lot of asylum seekers don't use their real name for obvious reasons. If your government were really persecuting you and trying to kill you would you use your real name? It might be a mistake to do it but it could save your life...

Comment: @MD-Tech, western nations **demand** that asylum seekers provide truthful information about their circumstances, including their real name. They're not the ones doing the persecution, or the refugee wouldn't ask for asylum there.

Answer (score 25):

We can't know that. The US and UK share plenty of information, and the full extent is still classified. If the US ever got that data, they may or may not have kept it.

This may not help **you**, but **others** who read this should note how *one* lie a long time ago comes back to haunt you.

Answer (score -10):

Disclaimer—Not a top-secret government guy

#### You are safe

Government systems (both software and just people/policy organization) are always a big mess. Even between UK departments (e.g. police and border force), they wouldn't share your prints.

Between countries? There wouldn't be any intelligence sharing without really good reason.

Also consider how much people demand privacy these days, and how much trouble companies like Facebook are getting into constantly. If a government was giving away fingerprints there would be riots and protests.

Comment: "If a government was giving away fingerprints there would be riots and protests." Yeah, right.

Comment: The "really good reason" is preventing another 9/11 and the intelligence sharing program is called [Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes).

Comment: Harsh downvotes. It's fair to say, in the balance of probabilities you are safe.

Comment: Downvoting dangerously incorrect information is never "harsh"

Comment: Given that there is a very well-known program for the sharing of intelligence between the US and UK (in both directions), with a specific focus on people entering either country under false pretences or by the use of deception, this answer is demonstrably false.